# Can `7z` compress only the updated section of the file instead of compressing complete updated file?

Tags: compression, 7zip

First, I created a 1GB file and transfer into `/target` folder, then I compressed the file using `7z a targer.7z target`.

Later I append `hello` string to the tail of the 1GB file. When I re-compressed the `/target` folder using update option `7z u target.7z target`; I observe that updated file is compressed all over again instead of compressing only its updated section.

**[Q]** How could I force `7z` to compress only the updated section of the file instead of compressing complete updated file? is there any alternative compression methods to achieve this goal?

**Example:**

```
$ mkdir target
$ fallocate -l 1G target/temp_1GB_file
$ time 7z a target.7z target
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)    
Scanning    
Updating archive target.7z    
Compressing  target/temp_1GB_file
Compressing  target/target.7z    
Everything is Ok

real    0m23.054s
user    0m30.316s
sys 0m1.047s

$ echo 'hello' >> target/temp_1GB_file
$ time 7z u target.7z target # Here complete file has been compressed all over again.
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)    
Scanning   
Updating archive target.7z    
Compressing  target/temp_1GB_file    
Everything is Ok    

real    0m23.861s
user    0m30.781s
sys 0m1.192s
```

Here, as you can see, I appended file with '`hello`' string, and instead of compressing '`hello's` located file-block and merge with the already compressed 1GB file, complete file has be re-compressed again.

Comment: You'd need to use a block-oriented compression algorithm, but there are few if any implementations of what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find any open source implementation. I guess, I should stick with `7z` than. @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7z is not designed for that.

You can look at the [gzlog.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) and [gzlog.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.c) code for an example of how to append short messages efficiently to a compressed file.